# markdown-editor missing in vue-simplemde npm package

Tags: vue.js, markdown

After I updated vue-simplemde npm version from 0.5.2 to 2.0.1 I cannot find vue-simplemde/src/markdown-editor in node_modules
How I can replace it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the README, Instead of doing this for the old version:

```js
<template>
  <markdown-editor v-model="content" ref="markdownEditor"></markdown-editor>
</template>

<script>
  import markdownEditor from 'vue-simplemde/src/markdown-editor'

  export default {
    components: {
      markdownEditor
    }
  }
</script>
```

You now need to import it like this with the new version:

```js
<template>
  <vue-simplemde v-model="content" ref="markdownEditor" />
</template>

<script>
  import VueSimplemde from 'vue-simplemde'

  export default {
    components: {
      VueSimplemde
    }
  }
</script>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-simplemde